# Проектирование БД магазина

Tags: sql, база-данных, проектирование

Здравствуйте! Создаю игровой магазин и столкнулся с 1 проблемой.
В магазине буду продавать игровой статус, игровые деньги, игровые предметы.

У всех этих товаров есть одинаковые поля

```
1. Название
2. Описание
3. Цена
4. Картинка
```

НО есть и слишком разные поля для каждой группы товаров

```
Для статуса:
1. Продолжительность продажи
2. Время жизни статуса

Для Денег
1. Валюта денег
2. Максимально возможный баланс

Для предметов
1. Количество предметов
```

Как правильно составить БД исходя из таких полей?

Comment: А какую СУБД собираетесь использовать?

Comment: В PostgreSQL есть возможность наследовать таблицы. Как раз подходит под ваш вариант.

Comment: мне не наследование надо, а понять как правильно структуру делать. Я в принципе могу все в 1 таблицу сделать, но это неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется это субъективно. Если много одинаковых и разных полей и будет необходимость запрашивать объекты разного типа одним списком я бы сделал так:

- Создал таблицу GAME_OBJECTS с общими полями и полем TYPE указывающим
  тип объекта.
- Создал бы еще 3 таблицы: GAME_STATUSES, GAME_MONEY,
  GAME_THINGS с полем OBJECT_ID указывающим на поле в таблице
  GAME_OBJECT.

Если общих полей мало и данные не нужно запрашивать одним списком (т. е. нет необходимости например считать количество всех предметов которые есть), то 3 таблицы с дублирующимися полями.

Comment: мне придется создавать много одинаковых типов с разными параметрами. Пример: Vip и Premium относится к типу Статус, но Вип имеет длительность продажи 30 дней, а Premium 90 дней. Нормально ли так делать?

Comment: @lolokot не понял вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Тут я вижу два варианта.

1. Если категорий не много и сайт постоянно обращается к конкретным полям, то можно их вынести по отдельным таблицам. Это упростит логику для запросов и присоединения полей, но увеличит количество таблиц.
2. Если сайт часто обращается к общим данным и почти не затрагивает конкретные, то в общем случае можно добавить поле тип и присоединять таблицы исходя из него в представлениях для обращения к конкретике.

   ```
   [товар]
   -Название
   -Описание
   -Цена
   -Картинка
   -Тип товара(id)
   ```

Comment: Проблема с первым вариантом. При создании 3 таблиц нужно делать еще 1. Тип товара, куда будут отправляться ID от этих 3. Четвертая таблица нужна, чтобы оправить точный тип товара и товар в таблицу "Заказ товара". У второго варианта лишь тип товара есть. Размещать в нем доп. поля которые нужны не корректно, т.к. суть таблицы будет уже другой.